# How can I search for a package, using APT, by it's name only?

Tags: apt, search

How can I make a search by the package name with APT?
I don't want the package's description to be considered in the query.

Answer (score 3):

For that purpose, you can simply use:

`apt search --names-only package_name`

The flag `--names-only` will make the search take into consideration just the field "Package (name)". This can reduce the number of results significantly.

If you have, or want, the exact name of the package, you can instead use:

`apt list package_name`

For instance:

- `apt search vim`

returns more than 100 packages (package description considered for the query).

- `apt search --names-only vim`

returns around 50 packages (package description not considered for the query).

- `apt list vim`

returns only 1 package (package-name exact match).

Comment: ```aptitude: unrecognized option '--names-only'```

Comment: @Bit-Man Use ``apt`` instead of ``aptitude``.